# Key-dependent maps preserving association

Tags: associations, map

Suppose I have some association `a0 = <| key1 -> val1, ... |>` and some function `f[key, val]`.  I'd like to produce the association `a1 = <| key1 -> f[key1, val1], key2 -> f[key2, val2], ... |>`.

I can see several methods to do this, each of which feels very kludgy in certain ways.  In increasing order of how much they make me feel uneasy, here they are:

---

**Way 1: Forcing the keys in with `AssociationMap`, then just mapping.**

```
RuleWithKey[Rule[key_,val_]] := Rule[key, {key, val}];
a1 = Map[f @@ #, AssociationMap[RuleWithKey, a0]].
```

(Related question: why does
`a1 = Map[f@@#, AssociationMap[Function[ Rule[key,val], Rule[key,{key,val}] ],a0]];` not work?  I get an error "Function: Parameter specification `key->val` in `Function[key->val,key->{key,val}]` should be a symbol or a list of symbols." but I can define `RuleWithKey` just fine.  Presumably this is something to do with `Rule` getting evaluated in one context but not in the other?)

---

**Way 2: Deconstructing with `Keys` and `KeyValueMap`, then reconstructing with `AssociationThread`.**

```
a1 = AssociationThread[Keys[a0], KeyValueMap[f, a0]];
```

---

**Way 3: Creating a key-association with `Identity`, then using `Merge`.**

```
a1 = Merge[ AssociationMap[Identity, Keys[a0]], a0, f@@# ];
```

(We can assume that we know that `key /= val` always holds; there are even-more-kludgy ways to get around this, of course.  Despite this assumption, this implementation particularly scares me, which is never a good thing to say about a piece of code.)

---

**Way 4: Using `Lookup` operations in an `AssociationMap`.**

```
a1 = AssociationMap[ f[#, a0[#]]&, a0 ];
```

---

Can you come up with a better method (by the admittedly difficult-to-interpret standard of "feeling not kludgy to me")?

I'm primarily interested in performant code (say associations with $\approx 10^6$ keys), so deconstructing and rebuilding associations isn't something that I'm super-thrilled about.  I also don't understand what operations on associations are efficient or inefficient, so comments or answers that discuss why some of these implementations are fast or slow (relatively speaking) would also be helpful.

Comment: What about the following variation of your "Way 1": `AssociationMap[#[[1]] -> (f @@ #) &, <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4|>]`?

Comment: @J.M., that's slightly more elegant, true.  But my understanding is that none of the four solutions are as performant as I'd like (primarily because none of them can "guarantee" to the backend that the keys are still distinct and in the same order, in the same way that a `Map` can); do you know of any solution that might ensure this?

Answer (score 5):

This is not a complete answer as I have nothing to offer on the question of performance, but another way to obtain the result is to use `MapIndexed`:

```
a0 = <| "key1" -> "val1", "key2" -> "val2", "key3" -> "val3" |>;

MapIndexed[f[#2[[1, 1]], #] &, a0]

(* <| key1 -> f[key1,val1], key2 -> f[key2,val2], key3 -> f[key3,val3] |> *)
```